# How to determine maximum sum in a path through 2-D array when all positions cannot be visited?

Tags: algorithm, 2d, dynamic-programming

The problem that I am stuck is that a person needs to go from the top-left of a 2-D array containing integers to the bottom-right position, gaining maximum possible score, either moving down or right. However, if a position A[i][j] is less than 0, then the person can't move past it and a amount equal to this negative value will be subtracted from the score every time the person visits a neighborhood of such position. I know that its a standard DP problem and that I could make a array T[][] with T[i][j] representing the maximum score till position i,j from 0,0. However, I am unable to come up with any proper implementation of the condition that person should not move past the cell marked with a negative integer.
For example,
if rows=2;column=3; and

```
A= | 0  -4   8 |
   | 1   1   0 |
```

then i want the answer to be -6, i.e. the matrix T should be

```
 T=| 0  -4   X |
   | -3 -6  -6 |
```

1. Given that at the starting and ending positions the person is not 'robbed' off his
      score.
2. X denotes that the corresponding position can't be reached by the man. In the above case the man cannot cross A[0][1] to go to A[0][2]
3. T[row-1][column-1] is the answer of the question i.e. the maximum score the person can obtain starting from A[0][0] to A[row-1][column-1]

Comment: From what I understand of your question, movements are restricted to `down` and `right`, is this correct?

Comment: @juan.facorro: yes indeed. Also, if the right or down cell is negative, the person cannot go into it.

Comment: Why in this test case the answer is 0? Is it -6?

Comment: @dwrd: the answer is -6. The person is not robbed at the starting point where his score is 0. He cannot go to A[0][1] (as per the rule), so he proceeds to A[1][0] where his score becomes 1. But he is robbed by 4 units so his score now is -3. He then goes to A[1][1] where his score becomes (-3)+1=-2. However, since A[1][1] is also in the neighborhood of A[0][1] (the array cell having negative value), he is again robbed of 4 units. His score now becomes -2-4=-6. He then goes to the final destination i.e. A[1][2] where he is not robbed(despite the fact that A[1][2] is in neighborhood of A[0][1])

Comment: You could replace the negative values with -infinity and the add the values in neighbours. Solve the easier problem of travelling from the top left to bottom right now.

So for your given matrix, you need to solve the 
    -4 -inf 4
     1   -3  0

which give -6

Answer (score 1):

The idea is emulating inability to move into negative cell with negative infinity result that will be never selected as maximum.
Pseudocode:

```
int negativePart(int i, int j)
{
    if (i < 0 || j < 0)
        return 0;
    return A[i, j] < 0 ? A[i, j] : 0;
}

int neighborInfluence(int i, int j)
{
    if (int == Height -1 && j == Width - 1)
        return 0;
    return negativePart(i-1, j-1) + negativePart(i-1,j)+// so on, do not think about negative indexes because it was already processed in negativePart method
}

int scoreOf(int i, int j)
{
    return A[i,j] < 0 ? <NegativeInfinity> : A[i,j] + neighborInfluence(i,j);
}

//.......

T[0,0] = A[0,0];
for (int i = 1; i < heigth; ++i)
{
    T[i, j] = T[i - 1, 0] + scoreOf(i, 0);
}

for (int i = 1; i < width; ++i)
{
    T[0, i] = T[0, i - 1] + scoreOf(0, i);
}

for (int i = 1; i < heigth; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < width; ++j)
    {
        T[i, j] = max(T[i - 1, j], T[i, j - 1]) + scoreOf(i, j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was following the same train of thought as suggested in the answer by [dwrd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074709/dvvrd), so I tried implementing it in Python. There are a few things to consider that I hadn't thought initially but I think I finally got it working.

Here's the code, it surely needs some polishing up, but it's a start:

```
def get_score(M, i, j):
    "Get the final score for position [i, j.]"
    score = 0

    if M[i][j] < 0:
        score = -float('inf')
    else:
        score = M[i][j]
        score = score + penalty(M, i - 1, j - 1)
        score = score + penalty(M, i - 1, j + 1)
        score = score + penalty(M, i + 1, j - 1)
        score = score + penalty(M, i + 1, j + 1)
        score = score + penalty(M, i - 1, j)
        score = score + penalty(M, i, j - 1)
        score = score + penalty(M, i + 1, j)
        score = score + penalty(M, i, j + 1)

    return  score

def penalty(M, i, j):
    "Calculate the penalty for position [i, j] if any."
    if i >= 0 and i < len(M) and j >= 0 and j < len(M[0]):
        return (0 if M[i][j] > 0 else M[i][j])

    return 0

def calc_scores(M):
    "Calculate the scores matrix T."
    w = len(M[0])
    h = len(M)
    T = [[0 for _ in range(w)] for _ in range(h)]

    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            T[i][j] = get_score(M, i, j)

    T[0][0] = 0
    T[h - 1][w - 1] = 0

    return T

def calc_max_score(A, T):
    "Calculate max score."
    w = len(A[0])
    h = len(A)
    S = [[0 for _ in range(w + 1)] for _ in range(h + 1)]

    for i in range(1, h + 1):
        for j in range(1, w + 1):
            S[i][j] = max(S[i - 1][j], S[i][j - 1]) + T[i - 1][j - 1]

            # These are for the cases where the road-block
            # is in the frontier
            if A[i - 1][j - 2] < 0 and i == 1:
                S[i][j] = -float('inf')

            if A[i - 2][j - 1] < 0 and j == 1:
                S[i][j] = -float('inf')
    return S

def print_matrix(M):
    for r in M:
        print r

A = [[0, -4, 8], [1, 1, 0]]
T = calc_scores(A)
S = calc_max_score(A, T)

print '----------'
print_matrix(T)
print '----------'
print_matrix(S)
print '----------'

A = [[0, 1, 1], [4, -4, 8], [1, 1, 0]]
T = calc_scores(A)
S = calc_max_score(A, T)

print '----------'
print_matrix(T)
print '----------'
print_matrix(S)
print '----------'
```

You get the following output:

```
----------
[0, -inf, 4]
[-3, -3, 0]
----------
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, -inf, -inf]
[0, -3, -6, -6]
----------

----------
[0, -3, -3]
[0, -inf, 4]
[-3, -3, 0]
----------
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, -3, -3]
[0, 0, -inf, 1]
[0, -3, -6, 1]
----------
```